# Why is Files.readAllBytes() not accepting an encoding parameter?

Tags: java, character-encoding

Not sure I am understanding this correctly, but I was thinking that when I need to store a file content as a byte array in Java, I need to provide Java with the encoding of the file.

If I want to do it with a ready for example, I'll need to do something like:

```
Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(myFilePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)
```

Why can't I specify the encoding the the file when using `Files.readAllBytes(myFilePath)`?
I'd like to do something like `Files.readAllBytes(myFilePath, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`.

Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: An encoding is needed when trying to interpret _bytes_ as _text_. But `readAllBytes` does not deliver text!

Comment: With `readAllBytes` you're reading... well... just bytes. And character encoding, as name might suggest, applies to characters. You only provide encoding when converting bytes to text.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) and you'll never get confused about things like this anymore. There are a lot of questions here where people get confused about encoding, so it's not a simple thing (and this isn't a stupid question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you are rather getting it wrong.  But it easy to get it wrong ... if you don't understand the Java way of modeling textual data.

You are conflating the functionality of Reader / Writer with that of InputStream / OutputStream.

- The former allow you to consume (read) and produce (write) characters; i.e. textual data represented using Unicode code-points.
- The latter allow you to consume (read) and produce (write) bytes; i.e. binary or binary encoded data.

Now *many* `Reader` and `Writer` classes actually perform two functions at the same time; i.e. sourcing or sinking the data AND converting the data to / from characters.  In some cases, you can tell the class how to do the conversion step by supplying an encoding.

By contrast an `InputStream` or `OutputStream` is a source or sink for bytes, and typically<sup>1</sup> doesn't do any character translation.

In the case of `Files.readAllBytes`, the method is reading all of the bytes from a file and putting them into a byte array.  It doesn't take a `Charset` parameter because it is not designed to do any decoding.

On the other hand, `Files.readAllLines` does take a `Charset`.  That is because it is delivering the file content as an array of `String` objects representing the *lines* of the file.  To when converting bytes to a Java `String` you need to say how the text / characters represented by the bytes are encoded.

---

<sup>1 - Hypothetically it could ... but you will see that Java doesn't provide classes like `ReaderInputStream` or `WriterOutputStream`.  There is little need for them.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, really helps! And thanks for detailing the difference between Reader/Writer and InputStream/OutputStream.

Answer (score 3):

No, you only need a `Charset` if you want represent the bytes as a `String` (i.e. as text) because the *meaning* of the bytes depends on the encoding.

```java
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/temp.txt"));
String text = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

A single byte array can represent multiple different strings depending on the encoding and the bytes in the array are independent of the encoding, so it doesn't make sense to be able to pass the encoding as an argument to this function.

Comment: Only two diferent Strings? You might want to read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) too.

Comment: @Kayaman Is this a rhetorical question? Because I think it is clear what I mean or do you think otherwise?

Comment: It's not at all clear, and based on all the people who give wrong answers to encoding questions I have low trust on most answerers on these questions. Are you saying you *have* read the link and do fully understand how charsets and encodings work? If so, great! But still the explanation is lacking, as a `byte[]` can represent potentially hundreds of Strings in different encodings (I'm not sure if there's one that would be valid in **all** possible encodings).

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of simple answers to encoding questions on SO, but it's not a simple issue. That's why the answers are often flawed in some way (although they may work "by accident"). If encoding were a simple thing, Joel wouldn't have been able to write such a tirade on it.

Comment: Yes, multiple would be correct. I'm not saying there's anything wrong with the answer per se.

Comment: Indeed, I was getting this wrong then :)) It's much clearer now, thanks!